# Lua table as redis argument

Tags: lua, redis, lua-table

I am trying to make a `MSETNX` call on redis from a Lua script.
I need to set some keys with empty values if they don't already exist.

I tried doing it like:

`redis.call('MSETNX', KEYS)` with KEYS `{'key1', '', 'key2', ''}` passed to the script.

but that doesn't work because this call needs individual keys and values passed as argument, not a table.

This works:

`redis.call('MSETNX', 'key1', '', 'key2', '')`

but the KEYS variable is dynamic, so I can't do it like that.

How can I call `MSETNX` without having to explicitly list each key individually?

-- EDIT --

Is it possible to `unpack` and "intermix" values?

Can I pass `KEYS = {'key1', 'key2'}` and `unpack` it to: `'key1', '', 'key2', ''`? Thanks!

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood my problem. The question wasn't how to run this in Redis, but how to "break" my table elements into individual arguments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use Lua's `unpack` on the table, i.e.:

```
redis.call('MSETNX', unpack(KEYS))
```

Side note: don't use `KEYS` as your table's name because that table is used by Redis to pass key names to the script.

Comment: That's it! unpack did the trick! Thank you so much! Btw,would you mind taking a look at my edit for another thing that is bothering me?

Comment: Side note: I was trying to make an example, I am not assigning KEYS variable in the Lua script, but thanks for the warning.

Comment: I'm not aware of something like this, but you can easily iterate over the table to insert the blanks after each entry, and then unpack the whole thing

Comment: Side note: you should be even more careful with examples - people may actually look here some day trying to learn, and be potentially mislead ;)

Comment: You are right, I edited my question to try and avoid any confusion. Thank you for your time!